# Disable auto scroll on JQuery datetime plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am using a JQuery datetime plugin in my application. When I scroll down or up my page and if my mouse pointer comes across date field text boxes then it changes dates because of scrolling. Even if date is not entered in date field then also it scrolls up or down from the current date. How to disable the scrolling on these date fields. You can see this behavior in the official page of this plugin for **DatePicker** field here: 
http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set scrollMonth to false

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
  lang:'ru',
  scrollMonth : false
});
```

Comment: jQuery('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
  lang:'ru',
  scrollInput : false
});

Answer (score 11):

Pass options `scrollMonth` and `scrollInput` to false.

```
$('.myDatePicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker : false,
    closeOnDateSelect : true,
    format : 'd-m-Y',
    scrollMonth : false,
    scrollInput : false
});
```